# How do we prevent users from changing the Proxy Setting?

Tags: proxy

Our school is running Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop.

We have a server that filters/block websites via proxy. We need a way to prevent the student account(The account type is limited) from changing the proxy settings.

We have tried to use the "Users and Groups" to change user privileges but this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

set iptables on each PC and block access to any proxy (ports 3128, 8080) but your's. Or even better, use ACL in your own proxy which will deny access to any port except 'safe' ones.

Comment: How would I use iptables so that they can only connect to the proxy port of 8080?